# Importing timeseries data from a .csv into a dataframe that is between two dates

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to import timeseries data into a .csv only if the data is between two dates?

The code below can import all the data from a series of .csv files but is it possible just to import between the two dates?

```py
def getTimeseriesData(DataPath, startDate, endDate):
    colNames = ['date']

    path = DataPath
    filePath = path, "*.csv"
    allfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
    for fname in allfiles:
        name = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
        name = os.path.split(name)[1]

        colNames.append(name)
    print(colNames)

    dataframes = [pd.read_csv(fname, header=None) for fname in allfiles]


    reduce(partial(pd.merge, on=0, how='outer'), dataframes)

    timeseriesData = reduce(partial(pd.merge, on=0, how='outer'), dataframes)

    timeseriesData.columns=colNames

    return timeseriesData

    print(type(timeseriesData))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

def getTimeseriesData(data_path, start_date, end_date):
    dfs = []
    for f_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path, "*.csv")):
        df = pd.read_csv(f_name, header=None)
        # Date filter (assumes filter column is named 'date').
        dfs.append(df.loc[(df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date), :])
    dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
    return dfs
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a general answer.

First of all, you dates should be kept in datetime format. If you import from Excel in format like 'day.month.year' or 'day-month-year', I would use such function to return a datetime

```
def to_date(date, split_sign):
    date = date.split(split_sign)
    day = date[0].replace(split_sign, ' ')
    month = date[1].replace(split_sign, ' ')
    if len(date[2].replace(split_sign, ' ')) < 4:
        year = '20' + date[2].replace(split_sign, ' ')
    else:
        year = date[2].replace(split_sign, ' ')
    date = str(day + month + year)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d%m%Y').date()
```

Pandas has a function `pandas.to_datetime`  to convert dates to datetime, but for me it is not always working.

And then finction like, where dates can be inserted like [day,month,year]

```
def filter_df(df, date_from, date_to):
    date1 = datetime.datetime(date_from[2], date_from[1], date_from[0])
    date2 = datetime.datetime(date_to[2], date_to[1], date_to[0])
    return df[(df['date']>=date1) & (df['date']<=date2)]
```